# jQuery - Data from columns to rows

Tags: javascript

I have JSON file as follow:

```
{
  "EX_20":[["1","21","0","0"]],   
  "EX_21":[["2","22","0","0"]],
  "EX_22":[["3","23","0","0"]],
  "EX_23":[["4","24","0","0"]],
  "EX_24":[["5","25","0","0"]],
  "EX_25":[["6","26","0","0"]]
}
```

To table I want to view following:

```
<table>
  <tr id="rowM20">
    <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="rowM21">
    <td>21</td><td>22</td><td>23</td><td>24</td><td>25</td><td>26</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I try using following script:

```
var mPocetZaznamu = 6;      /* number of records (number of rows)   */
var nPocetBunekRadek = 2;   /* number of cells at rows (from JSON) */

for (var n=0; n<nPocetBunekRadek; n++) {
  var radek = $("#rowM2"+n+" td");       /* define of rows */
  var datas = data["EX_2"+n][0];         /* define data */

  for (var m=0; m<=mPocetZaznamu; m++) {      
    $(radek[m+2]).html(datas[m]);        /* */
  }
}
```

Can ask for help? Thanks very much

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Your loops seems rights but you still need to generate your HTML table.

Comment: `var radek = $("#rowM2+n+" td")` will only work if the table already has all the `td` elements in it. If not, you need to create them, not select them.

Comment: To cracker: Present code return table as: `<tr>1  11 ....</tr><tr>2  22 ....</tr>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop should be:

```
for (var n = 0; n < nPocetBunekRadek; n++) {
    var radek = $("#rowM2" + n + " td"); /* define of rows */    
    for (var m = 0; m < mPocetZaznamu; m++) {
        radek.eq(m).html(data["EX_2"+m][0][n]);
    }
}
```

You weren't properly inverting your access to `data` when assigning to `radek`. Also, the `m` loop should use `<`, not `<=`, as the loop condition.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/syywytw5/10/)